# I have a heater in a 3 phase (415V AC, 230V per phase) timber kiln drawing 43A per phase. How many kW is this?

Tags: power

I'm new to this subject, but I want to learn. I have an electric heated timber kiln and I want to replace the electric heater with an equivalent rated oil burner, therefore I need to calculate the output power of the heater from the available information. The electric heater has an input of 3 phase 415V AC, 230V per phase. The amps per phase when the heater is running is 43A.

Is the power = 230V x 43A x 3 = 29670W ?

Comment: Are you sure the heaters are connected phase-neutral?

Comment: It doesn't matter for the calculation. If it was a black box with a balanced load the neutral current would be zero and you couldn't factor it in to the calculations. If using the phase to phase voltage you would divide the result by \$ \sqrt 3 \$ and get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. You have 30 kW of electrical heating.

For rough oil calculation you can work on a figure of 10 kWh heating per litre of oil. For 30 kW oil heating you will burn 3 L/hour assuming 100% of heat gets into the kiln. De-rate for flue losses. 85 to 90% is probably a good value for a condensing boiler.

But why do you want to burn non-renewable oil? Shouldn't you be burning renewable timber? Timber will give you about 4 to 4.5 kWh/kg and you're already in that business.

Comment: Wait a day or two to see if anything better is posted. If not then please "accept" this answer to indicate that your question is answered to your satisfaction. See my last paragraph addition.

Comment: The burner fuel would be waste oil only. Using wood waste does make good sense energy wise, and we have plenty of it, but the capital cost of wood burners is high and they are prone to accidental fires, which is often devastating around timber.